# To overcome threshold error on lookup fields, is it recommended/supported if i only store the parent ID inside the child records inside numeric field

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, lookup-column, list-view-threshold

I have 2 lists Child and Parent inside a SharePoint online site, where the child list has a lookup field to the parent list. Currently the parent list has 8,000++ items as follow:-

[image]

so now when i create a new child record the parent lookup field will show this error:-

> This is a lookup column that displays data from another list that
> currently exceeds the List View Threshold defined by the administrator
> (5000).

as follow:-

[image]

so to overcome this error is it fine if i remove the parent lookup field from the child list, and just store the parent id inside a numeric field?

Any idea on this please?

thanks

Answer (score 4):

As per my test, if you **index** the source column in the Parent list, although the error message still prmopts, you can select value in the Parent field of Child list and save the new item normally to the Child list.

[image]

Comment: you mean i need to Index the Lookup field inside the child ?or i need to index the parent record? if you mean the parent record then which column i need to index the Id or the title or all the fields.. can you advice more please.. thanks

Comment: Index the column where the column named Parent look up from. Go to the edit column pages, see what you selected under "In this column". Index the column you selected under "In this column".

Comment: yes i already indexed the title field inside the parent list + the lookup field inside the child list.. the lookup field inside the child list references parent's Title field. but i am still getting the same error...

Comment: As per my test, the error message still exists, but I can select value in the lookup field and save item to list normally.

Comment: Yes correct seems it will work is we use the SharePoint built-in forms, but it will not work if we use the power apps customized forms

Answer (score 2):

To resolve this issue you need to make the parent column(which is acting as lookup column in child) as index column. So Let's say, The 'Title' column from parent list is created as lookup column in the child list so you have to make the 'Title' column in the Parent list as Index column.

Comment: yes i already indexed the title field inside the parent list + the lookup field inside the child list.. the lookup field inside the child list references parent's Title field. but i am still getting the same error...

Comment: The error message will be there but you once you start typing the value in the lookup field, you will get the autosuggestion dropdown.

Comment: this is not the case in my case... i tried using Power app custom form and the SharePoint built-in modern list form and the classic list form... and i am unable to add the lookup field